# Graph API Not retrieving data properly

Tags: php, api, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-sdks

I am using `Microsoft graph API` to retrieve my messages from Microsoft account using `php SDK` (https://github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-sdk-php).

My code sample is given below

```
<?php

// Autoload files using the Composer autoloader.
require_once __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';

use Microsoft\Graph\Graph;
use Microsoft\Graph\Model;


    //get the access token to access graph api
    $tenantId = "XXXXXX";
    $clientId = "XXXXXXXXXXXX";
    $clientSecret = "XXXXXXXXXXX";

    $guzzleClient = new \GuzzleHttp\Client(array('curl' => array( CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => false)));
    $url = 'https://login.microsoftonline.com/' . $tenantId . '/oauth2/token?api-version=1.0';
    $token = json_decode($guzzleClient->post($url, [
        'form_params' => [
            'client_id' => $clientId,
            'client_secret' => $clientSecret,
            'resource' => 'https://graph.microsoft.com/',
            'grant_type' => 'client_credentials',
        ],
    ])->getBody()->getContents());
    $accessToken = $token->access_token;

    //get the messages of user
    $graph = new Graph();
    $graph->setAccessToken($accessToken);

    $messages = $graph->createRequest("GET", "/me/messages")
                    ->setReturnType(Model\User::class)
                    ->execute();
    print_r($messages); exit;
```

But it throws me error as shown below :

> Fatal error: Uncaught GuzzleHttp\Exception\ClientException: Client error: `GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/messages` resulted in a `400 Bad Request` response: { "error": { "code": "BadRequest", "message": "Current authenticated context is not valid for this request. (truncated...) in C:\wamp64\www\graph_api\vendor\guzzlehttp\guzzle\src\Exception\RequestException.php on line 113

[image]

Is this because of any permission problem to access the Graph API? I have the following permissions set in the `Microsoft app registration portal`

[image]

As well as in azure portal

[image]

What may cause this issue? Any way to solve the problem?

Answer (score 5):

You are getting the exception:

> Current authenticated context is not valid for this request

since the acquired token is for application permissions ([client credentials flow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-client-creds-grant-flow)). In this flow, there is no context for `Me` since it represents *signed-in user context*.

To get messages in client credentials flow user needs to be explicitly resolved in endpoint:

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/{user-id}/messages
```

**Example**

```
$userId = "--user-id-goes-here--";

$messages = $graph->createRequest("GET", "/users/{$userId}/messages")
    ->setReturnType(\Microsoft\Graph\Model\User::class)
    ->execute();
```

Comment: I am not sure about this. But i tried /users/{user_email}/messages  with no luck. Let me try this btw

Comment: when querying with `/users/{user_id}/messages` its result in **Fatal error: Uncaught GuzzleHttp\Exception\ClientException: Client error: `GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/4eeeecfed49f7586/messages` resulted in a `401 Unauthorized` response: { "error": { "code": "NoPermissionsInAccessToken", "message": "The token contains no permissions, or permis (truncated...) in C:\wamp64\www\graph_api\vendor\guzzlehttp\guzzle\src\Exception\RequestException.php on line 113** error. But its giving result in graph explorer > https://developer.microsoft.com/graph/graph-explorer/